# How to close dropdown when it is rendered to other page in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a cart dropdown as you can see below:
[image]

So my problem is whenever I go to the next page or do something, it stays open. But I want it to be closed when I go to another page. For this my component is here:

```
<template>
    <div class="custom-select" :tabindex="tabindex" @blur="open = false">
        <div class="selected" :class="{ open: open }" @click="open = !open">
            {{ selected.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="items" :class="{ selectHide: !open }">
            <div v-if="defaultValue != ''">{{ defaultValue }}</div>
            <div v-for="(option, i) of options" :key="i"
                 @click=" selected = option; open = false; $emit('input', option);">
                {{ option.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        defaultValue: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "Choose an option",
        },
        tabindex: {
            type: Number,
            required: false,
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            open: false,
            selected: this.setDefaultValue(),
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$emit("input", this.selected);
    },
    methods: {
        setDefaultValue() {
            if (this.defaultValue == '' && this.options.length > 0) {
                return this.options[0];
            }
            return {name: this.defaultValue};
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I am open to any kind of solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Hello @magic bean, could you share the css code of `open` and `selectHide` classes. How you are switching to the other page? Vue router?
Also a demo in jsfiddle o something similar could helps a lot to understand better the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "click outside" directive, that executes a close menu function whenever you click outside the menu. Then you also call the close menu function when any action in the menu is clicked.

Example directive in main.js:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
      // Check that click was outside the el and its children
      if (!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        // Call the specified method
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event)
      }
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    document.body.addEventListener('touchend', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  }
})
```

In your menu:

```html
<div v-click-outside="closeMenu"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is helpful but as you see my cart contains the Go To Cart button. When I click it, it renders to the other page and in this case, it doesn't close. And if I click outside, it is already closing by itself

Comment: I don't see the code for your Go To Cart button, but I imagine it executes a method, or does something that could be put into a method. In the method you can call the close menu method before doing the Go To Cart code.